# What is the best way to handle deleting rows in Ag-Grid when using Redux?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Adding rows is pretty straightforward - just have to add a new row in my Redux store, which then updates my table.

However if I delete a row from my Redux store the row data still seems to hang around somewhere - I have a few custom cell renderers which will then trigger errors as the data gets passed to them from Ag-Grid, but the row no longer exists in my store creating the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately neither of these suggestions worked in my case.

Setting a debugger in my custom cellRenderer showed that the row had been removed from `this.props.api.gridOptionsWrapper.gridOptions.rowData`, yet the cellRenderer was still called for the deleted row.

The quick fix solution I came up with was just to test if the row (`this.props.data`) using the cellRenderer existed in `this.props.api.gridOptionsWrapper.gridOptions.rowData` in a `shouldComponentUpdate` within the cellRenderer.

```
 shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
const { api, data } = nextProps;

const gridRowDataIds = api.gridOptionsWrapper.gridOptions.rowData.map(
  row => {
    return JSON.parse(row.rowMetadata).id;
  }
);

const dataPropsId = JSON.parse(data.rowMetadata).id;

return gridRowDataIds.includes(dataPropsId);
```

}

Note: `rowMetadata` is just a hidden column used to hold various properties regarding the row, such as an id, visibility, if it has been edited, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Code example would be helpful here to figure out the source of issue- in meantime please check if after manipulating your store, you do refresh the grid data - something like:

```
gridOptions.api.setRowData(gridOptions.rowData)
```

More about ag-grid row data updating can be found here:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/

https://www.ag-grid.com/react-redux-integration-pt1/

Answer (score 0):

Data binding in React can be achieved by using a controlled input. A controlled input is achieved by binding the value to a state variable and a onChange event to change the state as the input value changes.

See the below snippet:

```
onRemoveSelected() {

var selectedData = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();
var res = this.gridApi.updateRowData({ remove: selectedData });

this.props.actions.delete(selectedData.id);
```

}